# How does Pandas resolve the function specified by name in df.agg

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning Pandas and Numpy, currently going through [this section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#aggregation-api) of the tutorial. I'm new to Python altogether, so this is probably a basic beginner's question.

Given this data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                      index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=4))
df.iloc[3:7] = np.nan
```

I can't explain the difference between the following results of [`df.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

Call 1:

```
df.agg(sum)

#Result:
A   NaN
B   NaN
C   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Call 2:

```
df.agg('sum')

#Result:
A   -1.776752
B   -2.070156
C   -0.124162
dtype: float64
```

The result of `df.agg('sum')` is the same as that of `df.agg(np.sum)` or `df.sum()`. I expected `df.agg('sum')` to produce the same result as `df.agg(sum)`.

Does Pandas have special logic to resolve these functions such that it would prefer `np.sum` (or run `df.sum`) instead of the built-in `sum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation you linked to, it says:

> You can also pass named methods as strings.

So strings are resolved as method names on the DataFrame (or Series, if you call `agg` on a Series).

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that I should understand *"methods"* as `DataFrame` or `Series` functions that are called with `df.function_name()`? (I'm taking method as meaning the exact same thing as function). That could be the nuance I'm missing

Comment: @ernest_k: A method in Python is a function that is bound to an object.  So if you are doing `foo.bar()`, then `bar` is a method of `foo`.

Comment: This also means that `agg('some_pandas_func')` is the same as `agg(pd.PandasObject.same_pandas_func)` - so, `df.agg(pd.DataFrame.sum)` == `df.agg('sum')`. Calling with a string is just short-hand to reach the function belonging to the object.