# When to quote a function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

What are the rules for when a[`groupby function`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) requires quotes and when it does not? For example:

```
agg_dict.update({k: 'max' for k in df.columns if k not in ['name', 'age')
agg_dict.update({k: max_safe for k ['name', 'age'])
```

`max_safe` is a custom function that I wrote. `max` will work in quotes, but `max_safe` will not. For example, without it, I get:

> AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'max_safe'

Why does one require quotes and the other does not?

Comment: Put the function in quotes if it's a `pandas` implemented function

Comment: pandas function quote , no panda function or self-def no quote

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have [the same question I had some time back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53436538/how-does-pandas-resolve-the-function-specified-by-name-in-df-agg), meaning that the "function" in question is expected to be a data frame method, if quoted.

Comment: @CollinHeist thanks -- is there a place in the docs that talks more about that? So 'max' is not the python built-in max but an actual pandas-specific function?

Comment: @BEN_YO what is a 'self-def' ?

Comment: @David542 user-defined function or non-pandas methods in general. In my experience, any method of `pd.DataFrame` can be passed by string name to `agg`.